# How to stream from soundcloud without using API In windowsPhone 8 Application?

Tags: c#, xaml, iframe, windows-phone-8

I Develop windows phone application and i want to stream audio from sound cloud without using sound cloud API ( i write this Code

```
"webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<!doctype html>" + "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + "<iframe height=\"1000\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/125791854\" width=\"1200\"></iframe>" + "</body></html>");"
```

and C# and  using web Browser Control In Xaml Page in  but when i Run it it load sound cloud site but the audio didn't run.

Comment: Does that work in IE on the phone?

Comment: it run on web browser control and audio didn't run

Answer (score 0):

Try [Background Audio Player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) , basically what you will end up doing is

```
new AudioTrack(new Uri("[your soundcloud uri]", UriKind.Absolute), "[Track Name]", "[Artist]", "[Album]", null)
```

Things to note :

1. Url should be something like : [http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[trackNo]/stream?client_id=[id]](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/%5btrackNo%5d/stream?client_id=%5bid%5d)
2. You need to wait for the PlayerState to change to track ready and then call .Play(),  This is due to the asynchronous nature of the background audio player. It actually resides in a different process than the rest of the code.